# C# - How to convert variables? (String, int, etc.)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, variables, converters

I am just new at C# and I want to know how to convert variables
I am using visual basic

```
String no1 = first.Text;
String no2 = second.Text;
String ans;
ans = no1 + no2;
MessageBox.Show(ans);
```

what is wrong in my code?
the first and second .Text is textbox's name
pls help

Comment: @SURACI, you could have found this in less than a few seconds by doing a simple google search.. come on now.. do you need the url to google.com..?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
String no1 = first.Text;
String no2 = second.Text;
int ans = Int32.Parse(no1) + Int32.Parse(no2);

MessageBox.Show(ans.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNumbers(first.Text, second.Text);
    }

    private void AddNumbers(string text1, string text2)
    {
        string no1 = text1;
        string no2 = text2;
        int ans = (Convert.ToInt32(no1) + Convert.ToInt32(no2));
        MessageBox.Show(" " + ans.ToString());
    }
```